# LidR if-loop on coords (is/isn’t inside extent)

Tags: coordinates, lidr, canopy-height-model

I'm trying to calculate metrics on a buffer around points with Lidar data. But some of my points are outside my Lidar area, thus my loop stops when it finds a point outside.
I was thinking about making another loop asking to put zeros for the points outside.

Do you know how I can do that ?

Here is what I have :

```
pts_essai = sf::st_read("pts_essai.gpkg", quiet = TRUE)
coords = sf::st_coordinates(pts_essai)
ctg2 <- readLAScatalog(getwd())   

list_M_solo = list()

for (i in 1:nrow(pts_essai)){
  
  roi2 <- clip_circle(ctg2, x = coords[i,1],y = coords[i,2] ,radius = 15) ## ici, pour voir le nuage de pts correspondant au point numéro 3
  
  las2 <- normalize_height(roi2, algorithm = tin())
  chm2 <- rasterize_canopy(las2, res = 0.5, algorithm = dsmtin())
  
  
  chm_rast = raster(chm2)
  chm_val = getValues(chm_rast)
  
  chm_val_array=as.array(chm_val)
  
#Metrics  
  nb <- length(chm_val_array[!is.na(chm_val_array)]) 
  nb_na <- length(chm_val_array[is.na(chm_val_array)]) 
  CHM_mean <- mean(chm_val_array,na.rm=TRUE) 
  CHM_sd <- sd(chm_val_array,na.rm=TRUE) 
  CHM_cv <- (CHM_sd/CHM_mean)*100 
  CHM_CC2 <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= 2))/nb)*100
  CHM_CC10 <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= 10))/nb)*100
  CHM_CC20 <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= 20))/nb)*100
  CHM_CCmean <-  (length(which(chm_val_array >= CHM_mean))/nb)*100 #proportion of CHM pixels above chmmean
  meansd <- CHM_mean+CHM_sd
  CHM_CCmeansd <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= meansd))/nb)*100   #proportion of CHM pixels above chmmean + chmsd
  

#Create the data frame
  M_solo = data.frame(pts_essai$id[i],nb,nb_na,CHM_CCmean,CHM_sd,CHM_CC2,CHM_CC10,CHM_CC20,CHM_CCmean,CHM_CCmeansd)
  colnames(M_solo) = c("id","nb","nb_na","CHM_CCmean","CHM_sd","CHM_CC2","CHM_CC10","CHM_CC20","CHM_CCmean","CHM_CCmeansd")
  
  list_M_solo[[i]] = M_solo
  
}

M_mat_fsolo = do.call(rbind,list_M_solo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have done it that way by clipping the plots outside the loop. That way the plots are extracted and saved in files for later use and 0 point file are discarded.

```r
pts_essai = sf::st_read("pts_essai.gpkg", quiet = TRUE)
ctg2 <- readLAScatalog(getwd())   
opt_output_file(ctg2) <- "Path/to/folder/{UNIQUEIDFROMSHAPEFILE}"
ctg3 <- clip_roi(ctg2, pts_essai ,radius = 15)

list_M_solo = list()
for (i in seq_along(ctg3$filenames))
{
  roi2 <- readLAS(ctg3$filenames[i])
  las2 <- normalize_height(roi2, algorithm = tin())
  chm2 <- rasterize_canopy(las2, res = 0.5, algorithm = dsmtin(), pkg = "raster")
  chm_val <- getValues(chm2)
  chm_val_array <- as.array(chm_val)
  
  #Metrics  
  nb <- length(chm_val_array[!is.na(chm_val_array)]) 
  nb_na <- length(chm_val_array[is.na(chm_val_array)]) 
  CHM_mean <- mean(chm_val_array,na.rm=TRUE) 
  CHM_sd <- sd(chm_val_array,na.rm=TRUE) 
  CHM_cv <- (CHM_sd/CHM_mean)*100 
  CHM_CC2 <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= 2))/nb)*100
  CHM_CC10 <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= 10))/nb)*100
  CHM_CC20 <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= 20))/nb)*100
  CHM_CCmean <-  (length(which(chm_val_array >= CHM_mean))/nb)*100 #proportion of CHM pixels above chmmean
  meansd <- CHM_mean+CHM_sd
  CHM_CCmeansd <- (length(which(chm_val_array >= meansd))/nb)*100   #proportion of CHM pixels above chmmean + chmsd
  
  #Create the data frame
  M_solo = data.frame(pts_essai$id[i],nb,nb_na,CHM_CCmean,CHM_sd,CHM_CC2,CHM_CC10,CHM_CC20,CHM_CCmean,CHM_CCmeansd)
  colnames(M_solo) = c("id","nb","nb_na","CHM_CCmean","CHM_sd","CHM_CC2","CHM_CC10","CHM_CC20","CHM_CCmean","CHM_CCmeansd")
  
  list_M_solo[[i]] = M_solo
}

M_mat_fsolo = do.call(rbind,list_M_solo)
```

But if you want to keep your code as is you can add a test `if (is.empty(roi2))`